# SimpleMemoryObjectStore error

Tags: mule

Why I'm getting following error when I'm using mule's objecstore. In beginning of flow I don't have anything stored to objectstore but I have default value.

Exception stack is:
1. org.mule.util.store.SimpleMemoryObjectStore cannot be cast to org.mule.modules.process.ProcessAdapter (java.lang.ClassCastException)
  org.mule.modules.processors.RetrieveMessageProcessor:151 (null)
2. Failed to invoke retrieve. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)

### org.mule.modules.processors.RetrieveMessageProcessor:177

Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mule.util.store.SimpleMemoryObjectStore cannot be cast to org.mule.modules.process.ProcessAdapter
    at org.mule.modules.processors.RetrieveMessageProcessor.process(RetrieveMessageProcessor.java:151)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)

---

Comment: Your exception shows you are passing null payload in Object Store

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some payload, can put null payload in object store

Comment: So it does not matter even if I'm using this defaultValue-ref="#[string:0]"? It is still empty.